# Should we remove the security-effectiveness tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-pruning

The [security-effectiveness](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security-effectiveness) has been used 9 times, and as far as I can tell, adds no value.   Every question is arguably in some way about security-effectiveness or the lack thereof.

It is my opinion that this tag should be deleted.   Thoughts?

Comment: I agree. Unless someone offers a better explanation, we will nuke it - or feel free to slowly remove the tag from q's manually...

Comment: I am agree with that too. Seems pointless having security-effectiveness tag while everything here are all security related stuffs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Agreed.

It's only nine questions so I have removed the tag from all of them. A mod can feel free to nuke it now.